# How to get the value of a textbox on the same page in PHP

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
<form action="" method="get" >
    <input type="text" name="un"> 
    <input type="password" name="un2" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<?php 
    $users1 = $_GET["un"];
    $id     = $_GET["un2"];
    echo $users1;
?>
```

I am unable to display it through this way

error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: un in C:\wamp\www\vas1\register1.php on line 31
```

line 31:

```
$users1 = $_GET["un"];
```

Comment: the $_GET are only set when you submit a page, unless the page is submitted you wont get the contents of the form elements. Also you have method as post which means you need $_POST not $_GET

Comment: Note that there are tools such as the Firebug extension to Firefox that are invaluable when developing this stuff.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a notice. You need to check if the form is being submitted:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $users1 = $_POST['un'];
    echo $users1;
}
```

You can't be using using `get` because your form is using `post`:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Comment: actually i want to display the values on same webpage so i have change "post" in form method to "get" but still its not displaying the values

Comment: If you change post to get in the form make sure `$_POST['un']` changes to `$_GET['un']` and change `!empty($_POST)` to `!empty($_GET['un'])`

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple issues in your code.

Firstly, on the first page load the textarea hasn't been submitted so the request data will be blank.  You'll need a `isset()` to test for it.

Secondly, your PHP is using `$_GET` when your form is using `POST` so you need to change those.

Putting it all together:

```
<form action="" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="un"> 
    <input type="password" name="un2" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['un'])) {
        $users1 = $_POST["un"];
        $id = $_POST["un2"];

        echo $users1;
    }
?>
```

Comment: actually i want to display the values on same webpage so i have change "post" in form method to "get" but still its not displaying the values

Answer (score 2):

you are sending the post request

```
   <form action="" method="post" >
```

and then you are getting the parameter 
in get request

```
$users1 = $_GET["un"];
```

you are doing wrong ..do this

```
   $users = $_POST["un"];
```

Comment: actually i want to display the values on same webpage so i have change "post" in form method to "get" but still its not displaying the values

Comment: @MaryamButt still u need help ? or u have ur solution